# Как получить доступ к приватным полям

Tags: java, рефлексия

Не получается получить доступ к приватны полям

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 public  static Object add(Object from ,Class to) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException {

                Object to2 = to.newInstance();

                for(Field field:from.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
                {

                    if(field.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class))
                    {
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        Field fieldFrom = from.getClass().getDeclaredField(field.getName());
                        Object value = fieldFrom.get(from);
                        to.getDeclaredField(field.getName()).set(to2,value);
                    }

                }

                return to2;

            }
```

Comment: из какой строчки эксцепшен то?

Comment: to.getDeclaredField(field.getName()).set(to2,value);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, проверьте так, я поставил `.setAccessible(true)` всем полям, к которым Вы обращаетесь:

```
public static Object add(Object from, Class to)  throws NoSuchFieldException,
             IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException {

    Object to2 = to.newInstance();
    for (Field field:from.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Field fieldFrom = from.getClass().getDeclaredField(field.getName());
            fieldFrom .setAccessible(true);
            Object value = fieldFrom.get(from);
            Field field3 = to.getDeclaredField(field.getName());
            field3.setAccessible(true);
            field3.set(to2,value);
        }
    }
    return to2;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, ни ничего не изменилось

Comment: @SashaBushansky попробуйте еще раз, изменил ответ, опечатался в первый раз

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало

Comment: @SashaBushansky всегда пожалуйста, обращайтесь